# npmjs.org - Unable to find a readme for

Tags: node.js, npm, markdown, npm-publish

I'm a lead author of the npm package `scramjet` - since a month I have a problem regarding the visibility of the `README.md` in npmjs.

The [scramjet package in npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/scramjet) shows:

```
"Unable to find a readme for scramjet@4.33.2"
```

But at the same time the README.md file is there and `npm` command doesn't complain about any info.

I checked if this is not caused by:

- external images
- length of the readme
- I tried publishing again

The [README shows up nicely in github](https://github.com/signicode/scramjet) and the file is also added to [`package.json/files` here](https://github.com/signicode/scramjet/blob/master/package.json).

I tried npm support, but they stopped replying so maybe someone here has an idea?

**Edit:** I'm publishing this from a tarball I get from github - so `npm publish <url from gh>`

Comment: It's a bit worse, since I do have another package `scramjet-core` that doesn't even have `files` key in `package.json`... and the same thing still persists.

Comment: The other thing that's odd about your pkg is... When unpacking a `.tgz` file from the npm registry typically all the package contents get extracted into a folder named `package`. However when unpacking your `scramjet-4.33.2.tgz` the content gets extracted into a folder named `scramjet-4.33.2`.

Comment: That is a fantastic lead, I'm publishing this from a tarball I get from github - so `npm publish <url from gh>`. I'll rebuild this script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your [scramjet-4.33.2.tgz](https://registry.npmjs.org/scramjet/-/scramjet-4.33.2.tgz) archive, that currently exists in the npm registry, when extracted produces something like the following directory structure:

```
scramjet-4.33.2          <-----
├── CHANGELOG.md
├── CNAME
├── CODE_OF_CONDUCT.md
├── LICENSE
├── README.md
├── docs
│   └── ...
├── greenkeeper.json
├── gulpfile.js
├── jsconfig.json
├── jsdoc2md
│   └── ...
├── lib
│   └── ...
├── package-lock.json
├── package.json
└── ...
```

**Note:** the name of the root directory (indicated above) is currently `scramjet-4.33.2`

NPM expects the root directory to be named `package` therefore it is unable to find the `README.md`.

To clarify further, your `.tgz`  directory structure should be as follows:

```
package                  <----- Note: changed to `package`
├── CHANGELOG.md
├── CNAME
├── CODE_OF_CONDUCT.md
├── LICENSE
├── README.md
├── docs
│   └── ...
├── greenkeeper.json
├── gulpfile.js
├── jsconfig.json
├── jsdoc2md
│   └── ...
├── lib
│   └── ...
├── package-lock.json
├── package.json
└── ...
```

**Edit from author of the question:**

Additonally some background - the above situation happens if you try to publish your packages straight from `github` releases which used to work before, so don't do this anymore:

```
npm publish https://github.com/anorg/arepo/archive/v1.2.3.tar.gz
```

Instead use `npm pack` to create a tarball or just run `npm publish` in your working copy.