# Is the format of NPM pack specified?

Tags: npm, npm-pack

When I run `npm pack` it produces a `.tgz` with all the contents inside of `./package/`. Is the behavior of `npm pack` specified anywhere?

Comment: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/commands/npm-pack?

Comment: What do you mean by behaviour? If you mean how should the directory for thé resultant `.tgz` be structured, then it’s worth noting that NPM expects the root directory in thé tarball (`.tgz`) to be named `package` - see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62692052/npmjs-org-unable-to-find-a-readme-for/62694753#62694753)

Comment: @paolostyle that doesn't say anything about the directory structure, at all.

Comment: @RobC that does hit on what I'm talking about but only insofar as it infers it the same way I'm inferring it.  I'll update the example for more about what I'm looking for.